# When the following code is executed, this error appears

Tags: flutter

```
onPressed: () async {
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('/chats/oXbsPJbvNCK7Dzu9MY5S/messages').snapshots().listen((event) {
    print(event.docs[0]);
  });
}
```

Error message:

> Stream closed with status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE,
> description=403:Forbidden, cause=null}.

Answer (score 0):

The code 403 Forbidden means the API or in your case the Firebase is denying you access to the data you are requesting. You probably have something wrong with your authentication credentials.

Comment: Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.

Comment: It also appeared when I tried to create an account